# Multi level multi select dependent picklists

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, field-update, dependent-picklist

I have an interesting question which I am having trouble solving. The table below will show you better what I have to do.

[image: some table]

Based on a multi-select picklist (column OU in the table above) the user is going to select several countries. Based on that selection - a field will be updated with the corresponding cluster values(could be multiple). After all this is done, another field should show in which region/s those clusters belong to.

My question is if anyone has an idea on how to accomplish this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**First Step**, create 3 picklists:

1. Picklist with 2 regions (Region 1 and Region2)
2. Picklist with Clusters 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.
3. Picklist with Countries 1 till 23.

Note: If you want to work with multi picklists select them from the field opportunities.*

**Second Step**, create field dependencies.
You can locate them in Fields(second right button from when creating new field).

Then select **New** and select the values that you want:

- **Controlling Field**: (should be picklist 1)
- **Dependent Field**: (should be
  picklist 2)

Next you will get a window where you select the values from **picklist 2 and include them into picklist 1.**

The window will look something like this.[image]

**Third Step**, Do Step two for Picklist 2 and Picklist 3.

That is all, now when you go to the picklists, and open any of them you will get 3 fields to populate(Regions,Clusters,Countries),

Comment: @AlbertHristov tell me if this works for you, thanks.

Comment: hey, I meant something else in terms of business logic so this wasn't relevant but thanks for the tryout :) I ended up accomplishing this with some visualforce pages and styling them as normal fields. Thanks!